# Kotlin: FInd closest divisible

Tags: kotlin, math, integer, division

Is there function in kotlin stdlib to get closest divisible number like this:
 `fun closestDivisible(initialValue: Number, divisibleBy: Int)`

Comment: I'm not aware of such a thing, but this should be easy to write yourself, right?

Comment: There is no out of box method in Kotlin for this

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by closest divisible; you could help others help you by being more explicit about what you need to do. That said, it seems likely that `Math.floor`, `Math.ceil`, and/or `Math.round` might come into the picture. By the way, others will be more willing to help when you show what you've already done.

Comment: @Sweeper A snarky response is satisfying, but not really constructive.

Comment: For readability, I'd name this as an extension function: `fun Number.closestMultipleOf(factor: Int)`. You could then call it as e.g. `someVariable.closestMultipleOf(10)`, which makes the meaning clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no predefined function but there is a solution:

```
fun closestDivisible(initialValue: Int, divisibleBy: Int): Number {
    val quotient = initialValue.toDouble() / divisibleBy
    val floor = floor(quotient).toInt()
    val ceil = ceil(quotient).toInt()
    return when {
        (initialValue - floor * divisibleBy) < (ceil * divisibleBy - initialValue) -> floor * divisibleBy
        else -> ceil * divisibleBy
    }
}
```

This function returns the closest number that is divisible by 'divisibleBy'.

Comment: Your code seems to be correct, but your comment is not reflecting that: The result of your code can also be smaller than _initialValue_.

Comment: You are right. I edited the solution to find the closest number

Comment: I think you misunderstood my first comment: what I meant was that your comment below your code was in my opinion wrong, not the code itself. Now your new code does not produce the correct result for all cases (for example for negative _divisibleBy_).

Comment: What result does this give for inputs of `initialValue=-4` and `divisibleBy=2`?

Comment: The result is -2
@MarkDickinson

Comment: @Abolfazl: Thanks; that's what I suspected. But the closest value to `-4` that's divisible by `2` is surely `-4`, right? `-2` doesn't seem like the right answer here.

Comment: @MarkDickinson
it's true.
I changed the code accordingly

Comment: Thanks. I still have doubts about the correctness for negative `initialValue`. What if `initialValue=-2` and `divisibleBy=3`? I'd expect an answer of `-3`, but I suspect that your code would produce `0`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson You are right.
I edited the code to return the correct result.